# v-data-table component not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a sudo data table using vuetify.
The purpose is to render dynamically computed data using v-data-table

However, I am having trouble adding Vuetify to my application.

I tried adding

```
vue.use(Vuefity)
```

but it throws an error -> `Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof`

This is what my code looks like

```js
computed: {
      headers(): string[] {
        return ["test1"]
      },
      items(): string[] {
        return ["test", "t2"];
      }
}
```

```html
<div>
    This is new data
    {{items[0]}}
    <v-data-table
       :items-per-page="5"
       :items="items"
       :headers="headers"
       class="elevation-1"> 
    </v-data-table>
</div>
```

This is what my main.ts looks like

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css"
import Vuetify from "vuetify"


//Vue.use(Vuetify);
//Vue.readonly(Vuetify);

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

When I trying running the code the browser is unable to detect v-data-table.
And throws the following error:

`Failed to resolve component: v-data-table`

Answer (score 18):

Currently, Some components of Vuetify are not ready for production use in Vue 3.
But there is a way to use it in the project.
You can check further details in its official documentation of Vuetify from [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default createVuetify({
 components: {
    VDataTable,
 },
})
```

Comment: To add to this: if you added Vuetify to an existing project, the documentation tells you to `import * as components from 'vuetify/components'` and to then pass that on to `createVuetify()` under the `components` key. You can add labs components to this by unpacking the `components` variable and adding the `VDataTable` import: `components: { ...components, VDataTable }`.

Answer (score 1):

[Vuetify dosent currently support vue3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#vue-cli-install) use vue2. so `Vue.use` is not available in vue3 and because vuetify dosent added the `v-data-table` component is not available.

Comment: Vue3 is sort of a requirement. Is there any alternative to vuetify that works for vue 3?

Comment: Why is Vue 3 a requirement? Vue docs say Vue3 isn't ready for prod apps, so it really shouldn't be a requirement. The best thing to do right now is use the composition-api plugin with vue2 and then you can use Vuetify. Otherwise you're going to be out of luck.